# Finding the index in a modified Struts2 template iterator

Tags: struts2, iterator, freemarker

this should be simple, but I can't find the right variable.

I'm customizing a Freemarker template in struts2 (simple -> radioMap)

The structure of the template is basically :

```
<@s.iterator value="parameters.list">
   //Display each item in the list
</@s.iterator>
```

What I'm trying to do, is display the number of each item in the iteration.
I need to get the index of each iterated item, so that I can print

```
0 - Item A
1 - Item B
....
```

How can I get such an index?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `@s.iterator` is not a standard FreeMarker directive, I don't know if it puts the current index into some variable or not (the standard directive `#list` does, but apparently they use their own iterator for some reason). However, you could just count yourself, like:

```
<#local idx = 0>
<@.iterator ...>
   <#local idx = idx + 1>
   ...
</@.iterator>
```

Note that the usage of `#local` assumes that this "radioMap" thing is a macro. If it isn't, you had to use `<#assign ...>` instead, and then I hope this code is called in its own FreeMarker namespace (i.e., it's `#import`-ed, not `#include`-d) or in its own FreeMarker `Environment`, or else you can have name clashes.

Comment: I did have to use `<#assign ...>`. Thanks for the heads up about possible namespace clashes. I made sure to give the variable an adequate name.

Don't know if this might the the most appropriate solution, but it solved my problem well enough.

Answer (score 0):

The S2 iterator tag uses the `status` attribute to name the loop status variable.

The property tag can be used to retrieve the loop status variable.

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/iterator.html

To use the native FM looping you can use the `stack.findValue()` method.

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/freemarker.html